# Adding dynamic content to ScrollView causes jerk to bottom

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have implemented my own ScrollView that detects when the position of the ScrollView is close to the bottom and add views as necessary. The problem is when I add views to the LinearLayout inside of the ScrollView the scroll jerks to the bottom where I added some views. Is there anyway to add views to a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView that will not cause this behavior?

Thanks

Edit: This seems to only happen while scrolling. I have a case where I add views to the same ScrollView but by clicking a button rather than scrolling and I don't have the jerking problem. The new views just get added to the bottom of the LinearLayout being scrolled.

Comment: hey there buddy, sorry, its nothing for an answer, but i have been struggling to add views into a scroll view (linear layouts) - can share your code?